# Where does an Easy Extends version of Sonata Page Bundle put ORM mappings by default?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata

Our team generally uses annotations in our entity definitions to define ORM relationships.

I am now adding to a project in which Easy Extends was used to extend the Sonata Page Bundle.

It looks like my Page.php entity definition includes annotations for the JMS Serializer utility, but not for ORM relationships.

Is there a place where ORM relationships are placed by default when this set of tools is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sonata by default uses `.xml` for mappings, you can find PageBundle mappings in `src/Application/Sonata/PageBundle/Resources/config/doctrine`.